# Why is my simproc not activated on the prescribed pattern?

Tags: isabelle

I'm writing a simproc for sine simplifications. Here is an example rewriting sin(x+8pi+pi/2) to cos(x):

```
lemma rewrite_sine_1:
  fixes k' :: int and k :: real
  assumes "k  ≡ 2 * of_int k'" 
  shows "sin (x + k*pi + pi/2) ≡ cos (x)"
 sorry

ML ‹
fun rewrite_sine ctxt ct =
  let
    val sum = ct |> Thm.term_of |> dest_comb |> snd 
    val x = sum |> dest_comb |> fst |> dest_comb |> snd 
            |> dest_comb |> fst |> dest_comb |> snd
    val k = sum |> dest_comb |> fst |> dest_comb |> snd 
            |> dest_comb |> snd |> dest_comb |> fst
            |> dest_comb |> snd |> dest_comb |> snd |> HOLogic.dest_numeral
    val rk = SOME (Thm.cterm_of ctxt (HOLogic.mk_number HOLogic.realT k))
    val ik2 = SOME (Thm.cterm_of ctxt (HOLogic.mk_number HOLogic.intT (k div 2)))
    val cx = SOME( Thm.cterm_of ctxt x)
  in    
    SOME (Thm.instantiate' [] [rk,ik2,cx] @{thm rewrite_sine_1})    
  end
›

ML ‹
rewrite_sine @{context} @{cterm "sin(x+8*pi+pi/2)"}
›
```

Up to here everything works but once I set up my simproc:

```
simproc_setup sine1 ("sin (x + 8 * pi + pi / 2)") = ‹K rewrite_sine›

(* this should be handled by sine1 only, but is not *)
lemma "sin (x + 8 * pi + pi / 2) = cos(x)"
  apply simp
  sorry

(* this should be handled by sine1 only, but is not *)
lemma "sin(x+8*pi+pi/2) = cos(x)"
  apply(tactic ‹simp_tac (put_simpset HOL_basic_ss @{context} addsimprocs [@{simproc sine1}]) 1›)
  sorry
```

I see that it is not really applying even with a basic simpset. Others simprocs is set-up did work, see [here](https://github.com/rjraya/Tactics/blob/master/Tactics.thy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, your simproc is not called becaus simprocs (if I remember correctly) are only called after exhausting all ‘normal’ rewriting, and your goal is immediately rewritten to `sin (17 * pi / 2 + x) = cos x`. Since your simproc does not match that goal anymore, it is not called.

In the second example, your simproc *is* called (you can verify this by inserting e.g. a `val _ = @{print} "foo"` into your `let` block) and it indeed produces a rewrite rule. Unfortunately, this rewrite rule still has the precondition `8 ≡ 2 * real_of_int 4`, which `simp` cannot solve with the very basic simplifier setup you are using, so it fails to apply the rule.

You can find out what's going on there using the simplifier trace:

```
lemma "sin(x+8*pi+pi/2) = cos(x)"
  using [[simp_trace, simp_trace_depth_limit = 100]]
  apply(tactic ‹simp_tac (put_simpset HOL_basic_ss @{context} addsimprocs [@{simproc sine1}]) 1›)
```

Output:

```
[0]Adding simplification procedure "Scratch.sine1" for
sin (?x + 8 * pi + pi / 2) 
[0]Adding simplification procedure "Scratch.sine1" for
sin (?x + 8 * pi + pi / 2) 
[1]SIMPLIFIER INVOKED ON THE FOLLOWING TERM:
sin (x + 8 * pi + pi / 2) = cos x 
[1]Procedure "Scratch.sine1" produced rewrite rule:
8 ≡ 2 * real_of_int 4 ⟹
sin (x + 8 * pi + pi / 2) ≡ cos x 
[1]Applying instance of rewrite rule
8 ≡ 2 * real_of_int 4 ⟹
sin (x + 8 * pi + pi / 2) ≡ cos x 
[1]Trying to rewrite:
8 ≡ 2 * real_of_int 4 ⟹
sin (x + 8 * pi + pi / 2) ≡ cos x 
[2]SIMPLIFIER INVOKED ON THE FOLLOWING TERM:
8 ≡ 2 * real_of_int 4 
[1]FAILED
8 ≡ 2 * real_of_int 4 ⟹
sin (x + 8 * pi + pi / 2) ≡ cos x 
[1]IGNORED result of simproc "Scratch.sine1" -- does not match
sin (x + 8 * pi + pi / 2)
```

If you add the rule `2 * real_of_int 4 ≡ 8` to your simpset, it works as intended.